# Page Curling effect in android

Tags: android, page-curl

How to implement page curling effect in android on views which have dynamic data?

Answer (score 1):

Use this projects. This will help to implement page curl effect in your projcet :

[Page Curl for Android without OpenGL ES](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

The android page flipper is a 2D View which simulates a page curl effect. Without OpenGL, only the android canvas has been used, so that it can be used in any version of Android!

[Curl/Flip effect on Android using OpenGL ES](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)

Project for implementing 'page curl' effect on Android + OpenGL ES 1.

Comment: I've been through both of them but I am not able to use them to curl views.

Comment: My requirement:                                                         I've a list of mails, when I click on one of the mails, it expands. Here, I've a button which on pressed gives the full screen. The curl is to be implemented in this full screen mode, that is, when I move the finger at the right bottom, the curl happens and the next mail is shown.

Comment: Down voter  can you please tell me why you downvote my answer?

Comment: I downvoted this because it's a link only answer, which [is bad for various reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). This answer should have been a comment instead. Also while we're at it: Give links appropriate names, "Link 1" doesn't really tell a user immediately where he is going upon a click. "Page Curl for Android on google code" would have been a better linktext for example.

Comment: Alex I think you have enough reputation to edit answer then why didn't you? If you know there is something wrong with this answer you should edit and change that.

Comment: @VipulPurohit Yes I have enough rep to do that. No I don't edit things like that anymore, because that just ends in me editing a neverending stream of questions and answers all around here *(I've done so in the past, it gets anoying after a while)*. I rather say that there is something wrong and/or downvote so you try to improve it on your own. This way an issue gets fixed for all your future answers if you are receptive to criticism. Which in the end is better for the site *(less maintenance workload)* and you *(because your answer quality goes up, which means more upvotes for you)*.